# How to create a generic builder using TypeTag?

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, types, type-erasure

Given the following type hierarchy:

```
sealed trait Edge[T]
sealed trait WeightedEdge[T] extends Edge[T]
sealed abstract class AbstractUndirectedEdge[T] extends Edge[T]
case class UndirectedEdge[T](...) extends AbstractUndirectedEdge[T]
case class UndirectedWeightedEdge[T](...) extends AbstractUndirectedEdge[T] with WeightedEdge[T]
case class DirectedEdge[T](...) extends Edge[T]
case class DirectedWeightedEdge[T](...) extends WeightedEdge[T]

sealed abstract class GraphBuilder[V, E <: Edge[V]]
sealed class UndirectedGraphBuilder[V, E <: AbstractUndirectedEdge[V]] extends GraphBuilder[V, E]
sealed class DirectedGraphBuilder[V, E <: DirectedEdge[V]] extends GraphBuilder[V, E]
```

I want to create a builder method that dynamically determines which concrete builder instance to return.

```
def newBuilder[V, E <: Edge[V]](implicit tag: TypeTag[E]): GraphBuilder[V, E] = {
  tag.tpe match {
    case x if x <:< typeOf[DirectedEdge[V]] => new DirectedGraphBuilder[V, E]()
    case _ => new UndirectedGraphBuilder[V, E]()
  }
}
```

The above doesn't compile.

> Error:(119, 29) No TypeTag available for
>   DirectedEdge[V] case x if x <:< typeOf[DirectedEdge[V]] => new DirectedGraphBuilder[V, E]()
>
> Error:(119, 29) not enough arguments for
>   method typeOf: (implicit ttag:
>   reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[DirectedEdge[V]])reflect.runtime.universe.Type.
>   Unspecified value parameter ttag.
>         case x if x <:< typeOf[DirectedEdge[V]] => new DirectedGraphBuilder[V, E]()

Comment: Although, it is not very clear what you are trying to achieve (some use-cases, would be helpful), I think you have to supply `TypeTag` for `V` also. Like this: `def newBuilder[V, E <: Edge[V]](implicit tag: TypeTag[E], tag1: TypeTag[V])`. Then you type bound problem to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to supply `TypeTag` for `V` also:

```
def newBuilder[V, E <: Edge[V]](implicit tag: TypeTag[E], tag1: TypeTag[V]) = {
  tag.tpe match {
    case x if x <:< typeOf[DirectedEdge[V]] => new DirectedGraphBuilder[V, DirectedEdge[V]]()
    case _ => new UndirectedGraphBuilder[V, UndirectedEdge[V]]()
  }
}
```

Then fix, also what type of `Edge` to be created. At some point types should be fixed in some or another way when creating.

Then it works, although use case is unclear.

Comment: I omitted the class bodies for brevity. Adding the `TypeTag`  for `V` replaces the above compilation errors with another one, because `DirectedGraphBuilder[V, E]` does't conform to `GraphBuilder[V, DirectedEdge[V]]`. I gave up and simply created separate methods for individual builder types. Not sure how else to explain the use case, it's basically an immutable graph builder hierarchy.

Comment: What you suggested makes the return type of `newBuilder: GraphBuilder[V, _ >: DirectedEdge[V] with UndirectedEdge[V] <: Edge[V]]`. That doesn't work with pretty much anything. I upvoted you for addressing one of the compile errors, but perhaps this is not doable.

Comment: Yes, if you don't specify type, it will like that, other way you will need to cast like `instanceOf[]` of parent type. Still it would be simpler to approach with basic ADT I think.

Comment: "Basic ADT" for building immutable graphs - can you point me to some examples?

Comment: First shot: http://tpolecat.github.io/presentations/algebraic_types.html. ADT = Algebraic Data Type

Comment: I know what an ADT is, I wasn't asking for a 50000 feet view powerpoint presentation. FWIW, the class I'm trying to refactor is [here](https://github.com/asarkar/algorithms-design-analysis-2/blob/master/data-structures/src/main/scala/org/asarkar/data/Graph.scala)

Comment: Should not be that hard. There is `def addEdge(e: E): Unit = ???` function, that can be changed to `def addEdge(e: E): Graph[V, E]` from design perspective. Because your immutable implementation cannot return `Unit`. Then it will be used like `graph.addEdge(e1).addEdge(e2)` etc. Then you change implementation accordingly.

Comment: Dirty monkey typing refactor: https://gist.github.com/muradm/78a3b1f197671660a9c0e651fb36d91c. Better to re-design from scratch: a) since stuff is immutable, no need for builder any more, `addEdge` is actually becomes builder. Data storage could be re-designed as well.

Comment: Simplified: https://gist.github.com/muradm/78a3b1f197671660a9c0e651fb36d91c

Comment: I arrived at a very [similar implementation](https://gist.github.com/asarkar/1b4341671dd1402877e44a9962c8c331) independently. I certainly appreciate your help and value the time you put in, but I think we somewhat diverged from my original question, which was how to use `TypeTag` to create builder instances dynamically. Arguably, what we have is more type-safe, but better doesn't necessarily mean relevant. I'm going to send you a PM to discuss further.

Comment: Turns out after many, many requests, SO still doesn't have a [PM feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user). Good thing I've a [Gitter room](https://gitter.im/sia/Lobby) for technical discussions. If you care to join, we can talk there. Otherwise, I'm going to leave it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185343/discussion-between-muradm-and-abhijit-sarkar).